# Expanding mean of time delta

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
'timestamp':['2020-09-01 18:14:35','2020-09-01 18:14:39',
'2020-09-01 18:14:40','2020-09-01 02:09:22','2020-09-01 02:09:35',
'2020-09-01 02:09:53','2020-09-01 02:09:57']})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
print(df.head())

   id           timestamp
0   1 2020-09-01 18:14:35
1   1 2020-09-01 18:14:39
2   1 2020-09-01 18:14:40
3   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22
4   2 2020-09-01 02:09:35
```

I would like to calculate the expanding mean of the timestamp columns inside each id group, to reflect the average time delta in seconds between rows so the output will be:

```
   id           timestamp  delta
0   1 2020-09-01 18:14:35      0 - first row is always 0
1   1 2020-09-01 18:14:39      4 - (0 + 4) / 1
2   1 2020-09-01 18:14:41      3 - (0  + 4 + 2) / 2
3   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22      0 - first row is always 0
4   2 2020-09-01 02:09:34     12 - (0 + 12) / 1
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.mean())
```

but the output is the mean of the entire group. :(

Comment: If I got you right, lets try `df['delta']=df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (x.diff().dt.seconds).expanding().mean())` ?

Comment: Some timestamps from your output differ from your input. Anyways, I would go with the code mentioned by @wwnde. You can add `.fillna(0)` to the chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use timedelta in seconds for each consecutive rows in distinct group with a specific id. Get the expanding mean.

```
df['delta']=df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (x.diff().dt.seconds).expanding().mean())
```